# JSS: Target all direct children

Tags: reactjs, jss

I am using JSS with Material UI for React.js as it seems to be its preferred styling library.

Does anyone know the equivalent code for targeting all direct children in JSS? The equivalent of the following:

```
#divId > * {
  color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by keying an object `'&> *'`

```
  container : {

    '&> *' : {
    display : 'flex'
    , flexFlow : 'row nowrap'
    , border : "2px dashed orange"
    }
  }
```